# regex - match punctuation at end of word in Java/Scala String

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have this regex example at this link: http://regexr.com/39rr0

Text input:
     `1. This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait!`

Expected Output on string replace using this regex:
     `1 This camera support Monochrome Neutral Standard Landscape and Portrait`

I'm trying to remove punctuation which comes after words so I get only the words without it.
My regex is `(([\S]+)(,|:|;|\?|!))` and it matches fine in that regex editor. However when I do `string.replace( (([\S]+)(,|:|;|\?|!)), "")` or even `string.find( (([\S]+)(,|:|;|\?|!)) )` it finds nothing.

What's the regex to do this? Is my regex broken or am I using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use replaceAll, it works with regexp

```
System.out.println("This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait!".replaceAll("([\\S]+)(,|:|;|\\?|!)", "$1"));
```

Prints :

```
This camera support Monochrome Neutral Standard Landscape and Portrait
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `String.replace`, it only replaces literals.

Try a simpler `Pattern` and `String.replaceAll`:

```
System.out.println(
    "1. This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait!"
    .replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "")
);
```

**Output**

```
1 This camera support Monochrome Neutral Standard Landscape and Portrait
```

**Note**

If you only need to replace punctuation after a word character (an alphanumeric), you can improve the `Pattern` as such:

```
"(?<=\\w)\\p{Punct}+"
```

In your case, it will produce the same output.

Comment: do you know how to remove . from punctuation? I have words like i.e. and I would like to keep them "as is"

Comment: @Adrian you could use negative lookarounds for that, but then how would you differentiate with `"Portrait!"`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\\p{P}` to match all the punctuations.

```
String str = "1. This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait!";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\p{P}(?=\\s|$)", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
1 This camera support Monochrome Neutral Standard Landscape and Portrait
```

**Explanation:**

- `\\p{P}` Match all the punctuations
- `(?=\\s|$)` Only if it's followed by a space or end of the line anchor.